# Why does my ARCore AugmentedFace mask flicker?

Tags: android, glsl, augmented-reality, arcore

I was experementing with a tutorial project from [here](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/augmented_faces_java). I wanted the application to fill the user face with just one color. So I wrote new vertex and fragment shaders for this.

**my_shader.vert**

```
uniform mat4 u_ModelViewProjection;

attribute vec4 a_Position;

void main() {
   gl_Position = u_ModelViewProjection * a_Position;
}
```

**my_shader.frag**

```
precision mediump float;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

The application now draws one-color mask on the user face as I wanted. But this mask is flickering. I don't know what to do, because my shaders are very simple and I didn't change anything else in project.

Comment: I found out that flickering stops if I render more than 1 mask. For example, if I write `augmentedFaceRenderer.draw()` and `noseObject.draw()` there is no flickering. But if I write only `augmentedFaceRenderer.draw()` the flickering occurs. Of course, this isn't a good solution but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Try disabling multithreading. Also, don't use Vulkan API, use OpenGL ES 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use AndroidStudio and as I know there is no "multithreading option" (has read about it only in Unity forums). Also not sure I can switch from OpenGL ES2 to OpenGL ES3.